# User has excessive rights to W2k8r2 server even when she is a normal user

Tags: windows

Really wierd issue this one.  I have a user whose PC I have just joined into a domain which is simply a single Windows 2008 R2 server.

All users is map to a SHARE that contains their home folders so each user should only see his/her own folder.  But for this user after she logon to the domain from her PC, she is able to access all the other users home folders with full permissions!

I have checked her grouping and share+ntfs permission - all seem correct; effective permission on her account show everything is in order and that she does not have access to any folders except her own. Other users are not having this issue.

Here comes the wierd part:

- If she use another PC, her access to other folders on that same SHARE are correctly
  restricted.
- If another user logon from her PC, that user access is also correct.
- But if she logon from her own PC, she get full rights to the server!

How can this be happening?

Comment: Weird problem. So weird that it sounds like there's a facepalm kind of answer to it.

Comment: I think this one might be better for Serverfault

Comment: I'm not a experience Windows guy so any facepalm answer will still be welcomed.

Comment: is she an admin of her own PC?

Comment: Yes she is local admin.  The issue is not access to local drives.  She is map to a windows server share, and on her PC and only her PC, she is able to access all the folders in that share.

Comment: What rights does she have locally on that machine? Has she been assigned any extended rights on the machine under local group policy\computer configuration\security settings that may be impacting on things?

Comment: Just to add that we never found out why this was happening.  What we did was to delete those user accounts that got this unexplained elevated admin rights and recreated the users again.  After this, the rights appear correctly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If the homefolders are stored on the local disk, it might be that you have set her permissions to local administrator.

Comment: All users home folders are on the w2k8r2 server and accessible by a share.  Its this share thats giving her excessive full access but all the permission properties i've checked looks ok.

Comment: You say that the share is on a server. And that her computer is a server. Are they in fact the same server?

Comment: Her computer is a normal Windows 7 PC.  Server is Windows 2008R2 with folders shared out.  If she logon from her PC to the domain, she get full access to the servers' share when she should not.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run some basic tools to check the rights.

1. Test Effective File/Folder permissions. That is both share and ntfs.
2. Run RSOP for that user to evaluate group policies. Also check mappings and verify no permissions from elevated groups (if the user was in several groups and recently demoted) are not overlapping.
3. Check effective permissions for each group that the user is a member of.
4. Try resetting user account. Check logon scripts as well.

Comment: Thanks I will read up on RSOP.  How do I reset a windows user account?  BTW I have already check the basic obvious stuff like share/ntfs permission, group membership.

Comment: Simply disable, reset the password and re enable the profile. If the user is using a roaming profile, please check the settings as well. Re map all the mapped folders and printers. Apply a deny permission for the other shares which the user has exclusive access and check whether it propagates to this specific share (overlapping).

Comment: Additionally, reset the computer account and check. This is not necessary but I am suspecting a different possibility. Thank you!

Comment: I have reset the user account and computer account but it is still having full admin rights to the server's shares.  I have also run gpresult /v on the pc but not sure what i should look out for.  Any further hints?

Comment: Run the command after login as that specific user on Windows 7. When running the gpresult, you should also use /r option. Or else, if you wish to perform remotely, please use /user [<TARGETDOMAIN>\]<TARGETUSER> parameters. That should reveal any hidden configuration. You could also use auditing to understand the access behavior. Enable auditing for the specific share.

Answer (score 0):

This can occur when the [Windows Fast Logon Optimization feature](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305293) causes Windows Explorer to start before the logon scripts run. Having the Group Policy setting of ‘Run Logon Scripts Synchronously’ enabled and the setting ‘Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon’ settings enabled should fix this issue as described in [this Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304970).

More information on managing settings with Group Policy can be found on the [Manage and Operate Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd641430) page of the Springboard Series on TechNet.

Hope this helps

Comment: Could you expand on that? I can't envisage a situation where logon scripts being bypassed would affect a user's security group membership or effective permissions on a filesystem.

Comment: It appears that I may have misunderstood the question. I had interpreted this question as being an issue where a user is mapped to \\server\share\username, but the mapping actually ends up being \\server\share (one level up). My answer was not referencing the permission issue directly.

Comment: However, with that said, I agree with Lasith. But, the [RSOP page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772175.aspx) on TechNet shows that RSOP doesn’t include all settings for any OS after Vista SP1, and that you should use Group Policy Results or Group Policy Modeling options in the [Group Policy Management Console](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771009.aspx), or use the [GPResult](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160(v=ws.10).aspx) command line tool.

Comment: I have run gpresult /v on the pc, what should i look for to figure out how the user is getting admin rights?